# Can't communicate with SIM900a from PC via TTL

Tags: gsm, ttl, sim900

I've connected my SIM900a module with PC by using a TTL converter. I've tried two or three terminal (including putty and TMFT) to communicate with this module. But none of them are working. I can't even write anything on these terminal! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What (TTL) settings were used in putty?

Comment: Baud rate has set to 9600 and I'm using COM4.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your PC's TX pin to RX pin of SIM900A and PC's RX pin to TX pin of SIM900A.
You also need to connect your TTL converter's power supply to VMCU pin. This is generally the voltage level of your UART TX & RX pins.

You may also needs to  ground the PWRKEY for a second or two to turn the module on.

Serial Port Settings :

1. Baud Rate         : 9600
2. No. of Bits       : 8
3. No. of Stop Bits  : 1
4. Soft-Flow Control : None
5. Hard-Flow Control : None

If baud rate of 9600 doesn't work you cal also try a baud rate of 115200.

Don't forget to include carriage return character at end of each command.

e.g.

```
const char *at_test = "AT\r"
```